# NotAllowedError when trying to access AppStats

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

After doing everything from here 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html
I get

```
    <class 'google.appengine.api.users.NotAllowedError'>: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/ui.py", line 324, in <module>
    main()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/ui.py", line 320, in main
    util.run_bare_wsgi_app(app)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 116, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/appstats/ui.py", line 308, in __call__
    users.create_login_url(os.getenv('PATH_INFO', '')))])
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 256, in create_login_url
    raise NotAllowedError
```

when trying to access myapp.appspot.com/_ah/stats   or just myapp.appspot.com/stats/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have created your app with authentication set to only allow users from your Google Apps domain, but you're attempting to access appstats via the `appspot.com` subdomain. Try again using the URL for your app on your custom domain.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: @pyeleven Okay, what's your App ID, and how are you trying to access this?