# NotAllowedError create_login_url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception

**Update3**

In desperation I have created a new google appengine app which is identical to the original, even in name, but with a slightly longer ID. The new app has [-232619 added to the ID](http://participoll-232619.appspot.com), the original app has the briefer ID. The NEW app works as expected, but the original app produces the NotAllowedError still.

So, in my judgement, the problem is in google's system somehow, but I have not been able to get any human at google to give me a solution that will enable me to keep the original ID of the app. It seems that a human administrator would have to delete my original app named Participoll but somehow let me replace it. Replacing it would be complicated because the app creation system would also have to remove the name Participoll long enough so that I could claim the app name/ID again.

So I have the same app in 2 gae places, both have the EXACT same project name, but slightly different project IDs. The app with the stupid ID works, but no one can help me make the one with the desired ID work. How can this be fixed? I cannot delete the app with the desired ID because I will lose the desired name.

Can someone at google help here, please?

**Update3**

**Update2**

Chrome produces different results Safari from Firefox.

`participoll.appspot.com` produces `ApplicationError: 2` on Chrome, and `Error: Server Error (500)` on both Safari and Firefox.

`participoll.appspot.com/admin` produces `You are an administrator.` on Chrome, and `You are not logged in.` on both Safari and Firefox.

So, it looks like all 3 may be thinking I am an administrator, which I am. But none of the 3 have asked me to login, and I don't know how to force a logout or login request except in Chrome which is attached to google app engine, of course.

Does this give anyone any more ideas what can be going on?

**Update2**

**Update1**

More recently, using the "revised" simple app I am getting a different and more descriptive error message, which I show below. The new error refers to `create_logout_url` instead of `create_login_url` and the 500 error has disappeared.

Since the original `500 error` appeared -- not disappeared as I incorrectly typed, I temporarily commented out the login requests and assigned `login_url = 'login_url'` and `logout_url = 'logout_url'`; maybe this made the `500 error` disappear. That was encouraging because the `500 error` was so un-informative. So, maybe that change temporarily got around some other problem. But now I am getting this new error. (But see below, because Safari browser still has the `500 error`.)

```
    ApplicationError: 2 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~participoll/1.418713147155852221/main.py", line 33, in get
    logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 299, in create_logout_url
    raise e
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 2 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 273, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~participoll/1.418713147155852221/main.py", line 33, in get
    logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/a19f7fde5f64c33c/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 299, in create_logout_url
    raise e
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 2
```

When I ask for more information from Chrome regarding its "Not Secure" notification, it tells me that 1 cookie is being use.

**Wait** My comments above refer to using Chrome. I just tried Safari and there I am getting the `500 error` only.

**Update1**

**Update0**

The server error exception is 500 (I did not say that originally).
Even after changing the app's guts to include only a Google-supplied sample code, the same server error exception occurs: 500.

This app was never migrated from the master/slave datastore to the HRD datastore (because this developer was not informed of a need to do so). 
I suspect that the app has been frozen out of appengine because the migration was not done, but the kind Answerer disagrees (see comments to the Answer).

The revised app.yaml:

```
application: participoll
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: yes
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

The revised main.py:

```
# Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""
Sample Google App Engine application that demonstrates using the Users API

For more information about App Engine, see README.md under /appengine.
"""

# [START all]

from google.appengine.api import users
import webapp2


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # [START user_details]
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            nickname = user.nickname()
            logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/')
            greeting = 'Welcome, {}! (<a href="{}">sign out</a>)'.format(
                nickname, logout_url)
        else:
            login_url = users.create_login_url('/')
            greeting = '<a href="{}">Sign in</a>'.format(login_url)
        # [END user_details]
        self.response.write(
            '<html><body>{}</body></html>'.format(greeting))


class AdminPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            if users.is_current_user_admin():
                self.response.write('You are an administrator.')
            else:
                self.response.write('You are not an administrator.')
        else:
            self.response.write('You are not logged in.')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/admin', AdminPage)
], debug=True)

# [END all]
```

My goal is to salvage the name ParticiPoll for this app, whether the datastore is preserved or not preserved. How can I proceed? For example, is there some information at the developers' Google Cloud Platform, that I might use for confirming the datastore status or edit to avoid the server error?

**update0 above**

My app works in the local server but not in the public server. This suggests to me there is some problem with my app.yaml, but I have had no luck identifying the problem.

app.yaml:

```
application: participoll
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true 

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: markupsafe                                                              
  version: latest 

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

main.py

```
import webapp2
from views import MainHandler, TablePage, AddPerson, AddQuestion, Image
import os

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainHandler), 
        ('/table', TablePage), 
        ('/add_person', AddPerson), 
        ('/add_question', AddQuestion), 
    ('/img', Image),
        ],
        debug=True)
```

views.py (excerpt) (notice users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        ID_id = self.request.get("ID", None)
        if ID_id == '':
            ID_id = None
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if ID_id is None: #no ID has been set by the user
            path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'splash.html')
            if user: #offer user or nonuser options back at choose_name.html
                url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
                url_linktext = 'Signout'
                url_linktextmore = ' if you wish. You will be returned to this page after you signout.'
            else:
                url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
                url_linktext = 'Signin'
                url_linktextmore = ' if you will be creating a page. You will be returned to this page after you signin.'
            template_values = {
                'url': url,
                'url_linktext': url_linktext,
                'url_linktextmore': url_linktextmore,
                }
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Can I get help detecting and repairing this exception?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the dev server doesnt actually use the Google Accounts system https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/#Python_Google_accounts_and_the_development_server

A few questions on stack overflow seem to indicate that getting the `NotAllowedError` means you may need to do some extra configuring from within the app engine dashboard to enable it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676826/4458510

[NotAllowedError when trying to access AppStats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137479/notallowederror-when-trying-to-access-appstats?rq=1)

[Create_login_url error after migrating to HRD (Google App Engine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241127/create-login-url-error-after-migrating-to-hrd-google-app-engine)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/xH__FhRXOCM

Comment: Your link regarding migrating to HRD caught my eye. I don't think I ever migrated to hrd on this project because I never got a notice to do so on this project, only on 3 other projects. How can I determine if that is a problem, and if it is, does it seem like I can still migrate to HRD? [an example letter](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qltv/AmKK8MWBLZM)  says that migration is required to stop usage of the master/slave datastore. How can I tell if my app is attempting to use the master/slave datastore?

Comment: It looks like there is no longer a migration package to HRD. [Eg, looking at the glossary ](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/glossary#high_replication_datastore) and clicking on the HRD link does nothing: it's a broken link. I don't know how to update to HRD, but I wonder: if I update my source code to work with ndb instead of db, will that be enough, or do I have to also have to destroy the old  datastore, too. I don't know how to destroy the old datastore, but does changing the code to ndb do that? I am willing to, but not wishing to, destroy the old datastore. TIA

Comment: I don't think it's possible to be on the master slave datastore still and DB vs NDB are just different interfaces to the same datastore, i dont think switching would cause the backend to convert. But focusing on this issue, maybe create a fresh app engine project id, deploy this example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/users and see if you can get it working, if it does work, systematically add pieces in from you original project until you can identify the trouble-maker

Comment: I am not sure I exactly understand your comment, but I have used your link idea to test whether my project id is viable. That is, I put into app.yaml and main.py exactly the files at the link (actually the app.yaml has my application: and version:). When I deploy that test app, I get the same error as before. Do you think I might benefit by asking a new question on SO asking if there is a way to salvage my old app because I am really committed to the app's name? I am willing to accept your answer to this question because it has led me to question the HRD issue and whether my app is frozen out.

Comment: I don't think the HRD issue would cause this problem, it seems so unrelated. I was saying to deploy that example to a new project id to ensure that the example works fine in a fresh environment. If it DOES work fine, then you know there is something going on in your project that it doesn't like. If it DOES NOT work fine, then you know that the example you've been following is incomplete and that there is something else you need to do.

Comment: The revised test app works for any browser for `participoll.appspot.com/admin` and is throwing a new error in Chrome for `participoll.appspot.com`. But the `Server Error` persists with Safari and Firefox for `participoll.appspot.com`. There seems to be a slight difference between a plain user and an admin.  (The app revision in no way resembles the original app, but is Google's own example. )